# Why can't I connect to Oracle DB with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a oracle DB with SQLAlchemy however I get the following error:

`ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

Note that the code running this is on a docker container that is located on a vm in GCP.

I tried using tools like telnet, curl, nmap, etc and they all are able to connect/say open. So I don't see why connecting through python would all of a sudden make it not visible.

Here is the code that is used to try to connect.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from framework.db import BuildOracleConnection
Creds_Oracle = {
    'userName': 'urname',
    'password': 'pass',
    'host': '10.10.10.10',
    'port': '1521',
    'serviceName': 'svcName'
}
Conn_Oracle = BuildOracleConnection(Creds_Oracle)

metaConn = sessionmaker(bind=Conn_Oracle)
metaSession = metaConn()

sql = 'select * from table'

sql = sql.replace('\n', ' ')

sourceExtract = metaSession.execute(sql)
```

The part that throws the error is the last line.

I expect to be able to connect but instead I get the following error:
`ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`.

Comment: You can try by going through `sqlalchemy` docs on connecting to `Oracle` db. [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#oracle)

Comment: So when I run 

`engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://urname:pass@10.10.10.10:1521' + '/?service_name=' + 'svcName')`
`c = engine.connect()`

I get the exact same error

Comment: are you able to connect to your `Oracle` db through maybe `PL/SQL developer` or `Toad` if you have?

Comment: I've installed sqlplus and ran `sqlplus urname/pass@10.10.10.10:1521/svcName`, however the same error shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I wasn't able to connect directly to the loadbalancer, instead I had to connect to the nodes themselves.